# Как конвертировать интервал времени в дату?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Как конвертировать elapsed правильно в дату, чтобы отобразить в дальнейшем в формате времени?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
func stringFromTimeInterval(interval:TimeInterval) -> String {

    let ti = NSInteger(interval)

    let seconds = ti % 60
    let minutes = (ti / 60) % 60
    let hours = (ti / 3600)

    return String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d",hours,minutes,seconds)
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как вызвать эту функцию в моем случае, если есть startDate и endDate ? stringFromTimeInterva l(interval:  ? ? ? )

Comment: Так Вам надо тогда использовать другую функцию. Основной вопрос отличается от вопроса в комментарии. Ответ на вопрос в комментарии: let fallsBetween = (startDate...endDate).contains(Date())

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на конкретно ваш вопрос звучит так - создать Date из TimeInterval

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(date)
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: elapsed) // <- 
let elapsedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Если вас интересует более глубокая обработка компонентов даты/времени, то могу посоветовать обратить внимание на [Foundation.Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar)

```
let requestedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents(requestedComponents, from: startDate, to: endDate)

print("\(difference.month) Months \(difference.day) Days \(difference.minute) Minutes \(difference.second) Seconds"
```